# Swagger ignoring JAX-RS @Produces when Operation is not annotated with @ApiOperation

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, swagger

I am currently integrating Swagger (swagger-jaxrs artifact in version 1.5.7) into our existing JAX-RS REST application. After adding Swagger I added the @Api annotation to our interface class and already got a documentation which doesn't look to bad.

Unfortunately Swagger does not honor the @Produces annotations on my API methods until I annotate those methods with @ApiOperation:

Doesn't list text/plain as the returned media type:

```
@GET
@Path("/overallStatus")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getOverallStatus() {
}
```

Does list it:

```
@GET
@Path("/overallStatus")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@ApiOperation(value = "Get the overall system status")
public String getOverallStatus() {
}
```

Is there a way to have the media type in the Swagger output without adding @ApiOperation to all of them? Since the required information is already there, I don't see why I would need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `@ApiOperation` to your JAX-RS endpoints since methods without the `@ApiOperation` annotation will be ignored as per the Swagger Wiki page:

> Only methods that are annotated with @ApiOperation will be scanned and added the Swagger definition.

You can find more information here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X#apioperation

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true, since those methods show up in my Swagger definition - only the "produces" part is missing

Comment: Then the documentation is out of sync. However, looking at the code for scanning the annotations, it seems that it is expecting `@ApiOperation` be present: [link](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-jaxrs/src/main/java/io/swagger/jaxrs/Reader.java#L805)

Comment: Sad, but true - I don't really get why this is necessary. I'll create a feature request to change this behaviour then.

Comment: In case anyone else is interested: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1697